# An easy computation of the laplacian of $\lvert{f(z)\rvert}^2$ for a holomorphic function $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Narasimhan's book "Complex Analysis in one complex variable" ($2$nd ed).
After proving the weak form of the Maximum Principle (p. $25$, Theorem $3$), he applies the result to the function $u(z)=\lvert{f(z)\rvert}^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}$, and gets the equality (p. $26$, $2$nd row):
$$\frac{\partial^2 \lvert{f\rvert}^2}{\partial z \partial\overline{z}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}.$$

Recall that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$ by definition.

After many long computations (and a lot of time spent on it), I hope someone can help me to prove this apparently easily derived equality.

Please, tell me if I need to elaborate further my question.

Comment: apply the product rule first say to $\frac{\partial (f \bar f)}{\partial z}$ and then to the partial wr to $\bar z$ noting that $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}=0$ since $f$ holomorphic and same for $\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial {\bar z}}=0$ since $f_z$ is holomoprhic too

Comment: $\frac{\partial(f\overline{f})}{\partial\overline{z}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}\overline{f}+f\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}.$ Now, $f$ holomorphic implies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$, hence the $\frac{\partial(f\overline{f})}{\partial\overline{z}}=f\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}$. Now, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}+f\frac{\partial^2\overline{f}}{\partial z\partial\overline{z}}$. But...

Comment: ... second order derivative does not vanish, right?

Comment: $\frac{\partial^2\overline{f}}{\partial z\partial\overline{z}}=0$ since it is $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z}$ and $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z}$ is antiholomorphic still (or directly using that an anti-holomoprhic function like a holomorphic function for that matter is harmonic and that the second order partial derivative above is the Laplacian up to a factor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}}f\overline{f}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(f\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}},$$
because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z}=0$ from Cauchy-Riemann equation.